# Font Awesome icons not rendering on dynamically rendered partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, turbolinks

I have a partial in Rails that gets rendered after a remote `put` request via the `update.js.erb`.

The problem was the element, which is supposed to have font-awesome icons, is not rendering the actual icons. It has the classes but not showing the icons.

The icons appear if I refresh the page, also if I disable turbolinks for that page. But I don't want to disable turbolinks.

Any help?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I just found a solution. We just need to run the following code after the turbolinks:load event:

```
FontAwesome.dom.i2svg()
```

I found the solution here: https://www.nicholasshirley.com/using-font-awesome-5-and-the-rails-asset-pipeline/

Comment: That's great. I don't remember if I have fixed this, but I moved to other project now. Thanks anyway.